# How can I specify a custom criteria to sort tuples in a Python 3 priority queue?

Tags: python-3.x

Say I push tuples in a heapq, such as

```
import heapq
h=[]
heapq.heappush(h, (5, 'aaa'))
heapq.heappush(h, (7, 'bbb'))
heapq.heappush(h, (3, 'ccc'))
heapq.heappush(h, (-10, 'zzz'))
```

I understand Python will automatically sort the tuples in ascending order based on the first item, or the second, when the first is equal. How can I specify a different sorting criteria? E.g. I want to do it on the second item of the tuple only, in descending lexicographical order.

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html)?

Comment: Yes, I have read the docs.